# Firebase App Check C# Google.Apis.Firebaseappcheck.v1 library

Tags: c#, .net, firebase

Where can I find example code for Google.Apis.Firebaseappcheck.v1 library in C# (.NET Framework 4.8) ?

I want to use reCAPTCHA v3 , where can I find how to start ?

I found this link but I need some guideline to start

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/firebaseappcheck/v1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the .Net Admin SDK? If so, check out [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#c) as a starting point and then proceed through exploring using [the API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/appcheck/rest/v1/projects.apps.recaptchaV3Config) as listed in your message.